# Unable to verify messages from slack through AWS API Gateway to Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, slack-api

I'm attempting to validate a message from slack through my AWS API Gateway, an example of what I'm passing to my Lambda function is

```
{'method': 'POST', 'body': {'token': 'xxxxxx', 'team_id': 'xxxxxx', 'api_app_id': 'xxxxxx', 'event': {'client_msg_id': 'xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx', 'type': 'message', 'text': 'test', 'user': 'xxxxxx', 'ts': 'xxxxxx.xxxx', 'team': 'xxxxxx', 'blocks': [{'type': 'rich_text', 'block_id': 'xxx', 'elements': [{'type': 'rich_text_section', 'elements': [{'type': 'text', 'text': 'test'}]}]}], 'channel': 'xxxxxx', 'event_ts': 'xxxxxx.xxxx', 'channel_type': 'im'}, 'type': 'event_callback', 'event_id': 'xxxxxxxxx', 'event_time': 1576188370, 'authed_users': ['xxxxxxx']}, 'headers': {'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Host': 'xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', 'User-Agent': 'Slackbot 1.0 (+https://api.slack.com/robots)', 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': 'Root=1-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx', 'X-Forwarded-For': '54.xxx.xxx.xxx', 'X-Forwarded-Port': '443', 'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'https', 'X-Slack-Request-Timestamp': '1576188371', 'X-Slack-Signature': 'v0=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}}
```

An excerpt of just the body/request_body

```
{'token': 'xxxxxx', 'team_id': 'xxxxxx', 'api_app_id': 'xxxxxx', 'event': {'client_msg_id': 'xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx', 'type': 'message', 'text': 'test', 'user': 'xxxxxx', 'ts': 'xxxxxx.xxxx', 'team': 'xxxxxx', 'blocks': [{'type': 'rich_text', 'block_id': 'xxx', 'elements': [{'type': 'rich_text_section', 'elements': [{'type': 'text', 'text': 'test'}]}]}], 'channel': 'xxxxxx', 'event_ts': 'xxxxxx.xxxx', 'channel_type': 'im'}, 'type': 'event_callback', 'event_id': 'xxxxxxxxx', 'event_time': 1576188370, 'authed_users': ['xxxxxxx']}
```

I'm pulling out the X-Slack-Signature, X-Slack-Request-Timestamp, and the body of the object, then passing it to the following function

```
def verify_slack_request(slack_signature=None, slack_request_timestamp=None, request_body=None):
    slack_signing_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    print(request_body)
    data_body = json.dumps(request_body)

    basestring = 'v0:' + slack_request_timestamp + ':' + json.dumps(request_body, indent=None)
    slack_signing_secret = bytes(slack_signing_secret, 'utf-8')
    unicode_basestring = bytes(basestring, 'utf-8')
    my_signature = 'v0=' + hmac.new(slack_signing_secret, unicode_basestring, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

    print(my_signature)
    print(slack_signature)
```

The issue I'm having is that the slack signature passed with the method and my signature do not line up, I've been able to verify slack slash commands but general chat commands don't seem to be working using this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was `json.dumps` does not remove spaces between keys and values. The function need a `separators` parameter to remove spaces

Try the following code, you should pass pass the body of the lambda event as a dict (not string) to this function.

```
import json
import hashlib
import hmac

def create_signature(secret, timestamp, data):

    newdata =json.dumps(data, separators=(',', ':'))

    req = ('v0:' + str(timestamp) + ':' + newdata).encode()
    print('sigBaseString: ', req)
    request_signature= 'v0='+hmac.new(
        str.encode(secret),
        req, hashlib.sha256
    ).hexdigest()

    return request_signature
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204317/discussion-on-answer-by-arun-k-unable-to-verify-messages-from-slack-through-aws).

Comment: thanks @SamuelLiew, i was waiting for a chat option to appear

Comment: because all participants need 20 rep, otherwise a moderator needs to manually move to chat.